# angularjs view not updating with model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have an index page with a menu and a shopping-cart. You can view items and add them to the shopping cart. All data is from a server backend, and that part seems to work.
The problem is that the shopping-cart doesn't update when you add or remove items from it. You have to manualy refresh the page for the view to update. I have no idea where the problem is, so any hints would be appreciated
The backend is grails so there are some gsp specifics

index.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Load css files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: "bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/css", file: "bootstrap.css")}">
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/jquery", file: "jquery.min.js")}"></script>

<title>MM Antik Design</title>
</head>
    <body ng-app="mmadApp">

    <header></header>
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MMAD</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#salg">Salg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#galleri">Galleri</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="shoppingCart"><img src="${resource(dir: "images", file: "shopping-cart-32.png")}"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li id="sCart">
                            <div ng-controller="shoppingCartCtrl"> //Will not update unless manual refresh
                                <table>

                                    <tr ng-repeat="item in shoppingCart.items">
                                        <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{item.primaryImage}}" /></td>
                                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Checkout {{shoppingCart.quantity}} items</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
<!-- End Navigation -->
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <article ng-view="">

            </article>
        </div>
</div>


    <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="row">
                <p>&copy; <a href="http://randomthought.eu" target="_blank">Random Thought</a></p>
            </div>
    </footer>


    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/lodash/dist", file: "lodash.min.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js", file: "bootstrap.min.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/angular", file: "angular.min.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/angular-route", file: "angular-route.min.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/restangular/dist", file: "restangular.min.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "bower_components/angular-bootstrap", file: "ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js")}"></script>

    <!-- Misc angular includes -->
    <script src="${resource(dir: "app/scripts", file: "mmadApp.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "app/scripts/controllers", file: "homeCtrl.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "app/scripts/controllers", file: "itemCtrls.js")}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: "app/scripts/controllers", file: "shoppingCartCtrl.js")}"></script>

    <!-- ui controllers -->
    <script src="${resource(dir: "app/scripts/controllers/ui", file: "uiCtrl.js")}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

shoppingCartCtrl // The controller is quite a mess after trying many different things

```
mmadApp.controller('shoppingCartCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.shoppingCart = "";
    $scope.shoppingCart.quantity = 0;

    $http.get('/mmad/shoppingCart/show').success( function(data) {
        $scope.shoppingCart = data;
    });

    $scope.shoppingCart = {
        items: [{}]
    };

    $http.post("/mmad/shoppingCart/show").success( function( data ) {
            if(data.items != null) {

                for (var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++) {
                    $http.post("/mmad/item/show/" + data.items[i].id).success( function( newData ) {
                        $scope.shoppingCart.items.push(newData);
                        $scope.shoppingCart.quantity ++;
                    })
                }

            }
    })


    $scope.addToBasket = function( id ) {
        $http.post("/mmad/shoppingCart/ajaxAddToBasket?itemId=" + id).success( function( data ) {

        })
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `addToBasket` function, you need to push the data item into `$scope.shoppingCart`.

Something like

```
$scope.addToBasket = function( id ) {
  $http.post("/mmad/shoppingCart/ajaxAddToBasket?itemId=" + id).success( function( data ) {
  // do something to data, put in newData
  $scope.shoppingCart.items.push(newData);
  })
}
```

Comment: hmm, I tried doing that, but now it's like it pushes the wrong data the server returns the following in JSON {"class":"mmad.Item","id":1,"circumference":null,"color":null,"description":null,"height":null,"images":null,"name":"Stolen","price":337,"primaryImage":"http://lorempixel.com/400/200","status":"Inactive","width":null}, also it seems I can't use push on a null object the first time I try to buy something, I thought items was initialized with the items: [{}]; line

Comment: the `$http.get` will overwrite the `$scope.shoppingCart` when it returns. There might not be `items` anymore depending on the data that's returned. `$http.get` is asynchronous, so it'll overwrite `$scope.shoppingCart` after the variable has been initialized.